# Edit mode toolbar (additional icons) does not show up

Tags: interface, edit-mode

I have this issue with "edit mode". There is only a part of icons on the left side of the screen. Also there is no grid on the model. I guess the solution is simple, but I just stuck...
Everything works fine on other models.

[image: edit mode]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be because you are currently editing the **Armature** and by what you are describing, you may want to edit the **Mesh**. To edit the Mesh, click on the arrow next to the Armature in the object list to show the children objects of the Armature, then, click on the Mesh object and go into Edit Mode.

Comment: Thank You! Now I can switch from armature to mesh just for fun;)